# Rails 4: Autocomplete nor working using rails4-autocomplete gem

Tags: ruby-on-rails, autocomplete, has-many-through

I have 3 models with a has_many through relationship: Food (eg: Chocolate), Sub (Chocolate food substitute), Joint (joint table).

I am using rails4-autocomplete gem to run a simple autocomplete of the existing substitutes (from my Sub model) saved in the database, so that when I create a new food (Food model) I can associate this "new food" with an existing substitute if I want to. I followed the step of the [gem doc](http://www.rubydoc.info/gems/rails4-autocomplete/1.1.1) but I cannot make it work.

My problem is to make the autocomplete work so that upon filling up the form (in views/food/_form) it shows the already existing substitute (saved with my Sub model)

Thanks a lot in advance for your help, please find below all the relevant code:

### application.js: (here I require the autocomplete-rails)

```
//= require jquery
//= require jquery_ujs
//= require cocoon
//= require turbolinks
//= require autocomplete-rails
//= require_tree .
```

### My routes:

```
  resources :foods do
    get :autocomplete_sub_name, :on => :collection
  end
  
  resources :subs

  resources :joints

  root "foods#index"
```

### My 3 models:

```
class Food < ActiveRecord::Base
    has_many :joints
    has_many :subs, :through => :joints
    accepts_nested_attributes_for :subs, reject_if: :all_blank, allow_destroy: true
end
class Sub < ActiveRecord::Base
    has_many :joints
    has_many :foods, :through => :joints
    accepts_nested_attributes_for :foods, reject_if: :all_blank, allow_destroy: true
end
class Joint < ActiveRecord::Base
    belongs_to :food
    belongs_to :sub
end
```

### My food controller:

```
class FoodsController < ApplicationController
  before_action :set_food, only: [:show, :edit, :update, :destroy]
  autocomplete :sub, :name, :full => true

  # GET /foods
  # GET /foods.json
  def index
    @foods = Food.all
  end

  # GET /foods/1
  # GET /foods/1.json
  def show
  end

  # GET /foods/new
  def new
    @food = Food.new
    @food.subs.build
  end

  # GET /foods/1/edit
  def edit
  end

  # POST /foods
  # POST /foods.json
  def create
    @food = Food.new(food_params)

    respond_to do |format|
      if @food.save
        format.html { redirect_to @food, notice: 'Food was successfully created.' }
        format.json { render :show, status: :created, location: @food }
      else
        format.html { render :new }
        format.json { render json: @food.errors, status: :unprocessable_entity }
      end
    end
  end

  # PATCH/PUT /foods/1
  # PATCH/PUT /foods/1.json
  def update
    respond_to do |format|
      if @food.update(food_params)
        format.html { redirect_to @food, notice: 'Food was successfully updated.' }
        format.json { render :show, status: :ok, location: @food }
      else
        format.html { render :edit }
        format.json { render json: @food.errors, status: :unprocessable_entity }
      end
    end
  end

  # DELETE /foods/1
  # DELETE /foods/1.json
  def destroy
    @food.destroy
    respond_to do |format|
      format.html { redirect_to foods_url, notice: 'Food was successfully destroyed.' }
      format.json { head :no_content }
    end
  end

  private
    # Use callbacks to share common setup or constraints between actions.
    def set_food
      @food = Food.find(params[:id])
    end

    # Never trust parameters from the scary internet, only allow the white list through.
    def food_params
      params.require(:food).permit(:name, :description, subs_attributes: [:id, :name, :description, :_destroy])
    end
end
```

### My db-schema FYI:

```
create_table "foods", force: true do |t|
    t.string   "name"
    t.text     "description"
    t.datetime "created_at",  null: false
    t.datetime "updated_at",  null: false
  end

  create_table "joints", force: true do |t|
    t.integer  "food_id"
    t.integer  "sub_id"
    t.datetime "created_at", null: false
    t.datetime "updated_at", null: false
  end

  create_table "subs", force: true do |t|
    t.string   "name"
    t.text     "description"
    t.datetime "created_at",  null: false
    t.datetime "updated_at",  null: false
  end
```

### And finally mi _form and _sub_fields which is a partial rendered in _form where I try to use the Autocomplete:

```
<%= form_for(@food) do |f| %>
  <% if @food.errors.any? %>
    <div id="error_explanation">
      <h2><%= pluralize(@food.errors.count, "error") %> prohibited this food from being saved:</h2>

      <ul>
      <% @food.errors.full_messages.each do |message| %>
        <li><%= message %></li>
      <% end %>
      </ul>
    </div>
  <% end %>

  <div class="field">
    <%= f.label :name %><br>
    <%= f.text_field :name %>
  </div>
  <div class="field">
    <%= f.label :description %><br>
    <%= f.text_area :description %>
  </div>

  <div>
    <%= f.fields_for :subs do |sub| %>
      <%= render 'sub_fields', :f => sub %>
      <%= link_to_add_association 'Add sub', f, :subs %>
    <% end %>
  </div>

  
  <div class="actions">
    <%= f.submit %>
  </div>
<% end %>
```

### The _sub_fields partial:

```
<div class="nested-fields">
    <div class="field">
        <%= f.label :name %>
        <%= f.text_field :name %>
        <%= f.autocomplete_field :sub_name, autocomplete_sub_name_foods_path %>

    </div>
    <div class="field">
        <%= f.label :description %>
        <%= f.text_area :description %>
    </div>
    <%= link_to_remove_association 'remove sub', f %>
</div>
```

Thanks a lot in advance for your Help !
Antoine

Answer (score 0):

From all your code I can only guess a possible reason for your problem:

You're using the autocomplete field in a nested model form. The `link_to_add_association`-Link adds new elements dynamically to the page. Take care that the newly added elements have the necessary Javascript event handlers attached. The gem's Javascript contains these lines:

```
jQuery(document).ready(function(){
  jQuery('input[data-autocomplete]').railsAutocomplete()
});
```

So event handlers are only attached to elements already existing after page has fully loaded. Try changing these lines to:

```
jQuery(document).ready(function(){
  jQuery('body').on('focus', 'input[data-autocomplete]', function(){
    jQuery(this).railsAutocomplete()
  })
})
```

This way you attach event handlers every time you add a new set of nested fields.